# How to send a message to a specific channel as part of a slash command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

When I receive a slash command with my bot, I send a modal to a user asking for information.
All this works, however, as part of that, I would also like to send a message to a specific channel on a specific server (guild) to say that a request has been made.
I am having trouble with that second part.

```py
import discord

bot = discord.Bot()
client = discord.Client()

@bot.slash_command(name = "create-trial-request", description = "Create a new trial request from a bbcode template.")
async def trial_request(ctx):
    modal = my_modal(title="Fill this in please")
    await ctx.send_modal(modal)

class my_modal(discord.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.add_item(discord.ui.InputText(label="Some Label Name"))

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        
        request_number = request_number_generator()
        
        # here is where I want to send my message to a specific channel.
        # I know the ID of that channel, I just don't know how to send the message there.

        code_snippet = format_to_code(bbcode)
        request_response = "Created request #" + str(request_number)
        await interaction.response.send_message(request_response, ephemeral=True)
```

I have tried the following (placed where my comments are in the code above):

```py
        channel = client.get_channel(6648250855168XXXXX)
        await channel.send("Created trial request #" + str(request_number))
```

...but I get: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`

Obviously the bot has access to the channel, and if I write to it as part of the response to the slash command, it successfully writes there, but I can't seem to make it work on its own.

Is there any way to do what I am trying to?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should first get the guild from the client then get the channel from that guild object, also you don't have to mask your channel id, it's not sensitive. Another note you need guild intent enabled to use `get_channel` idk if pycord handles the intents implicitly but I wanted to mention it since you are not passing any intents to your client.  Also you have both `commands.Bot` and a `discord.Client` instance just use one of them  try `bot.get_channel`.

Comment: Hi there @3nws, yes you were entirely right, I should have been using bot.get_channel and not client.get_channel. It now works as expected. Could you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @3nws, I now know the answer to this question.

The issue in my case was that I was using both `client` and `bot` and should have only been using one of the two (in this instance, `bot`, since I am using slash commands.

There is a usable `bot.getchannel` command that does what I wanted.

I hope this helps anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all: Don't create 2 bot/client instances. Just use `commands.Bot` once. That's the reason you made a mistake. You used `client` instead of `bot`. Replace it and it should work.**

Otherwise, if it would be still `None`, here are some possible reasons why:

• Not subscribed to the relevant intent.
• Wrong key
 ◦ Remember, IDs are ints, not strings
 ◦ If you're trying to copy an emoji ID, right-clicking the emoji in a message will copy message ID
• Bot not logged in, and trying to grab objects from cache
 ◦ Subvairant, using two client objects.
• Bot cannot "see" the object. 
 ◦ It has to be on the server, share a server with the member, etc
 ◦ If you're sharded on separate processes, each process will only have objects for that shard. 
• Objects retuned by `fetch_x` will not have a populated cache.

It doesn't make a huge difference if you do `bot.get_channel()` or `bot.get_guild().get_channel()`. You can use both.

Answer (score 0):

To do so, 1. import commands aka from discord.ext import commands

Then remove your bot = discord.Bot and edit client do it is client = commands.Bot()

thats what i do

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32642585)